# How do I check if ConcurrentLinkedQueue leaves garbage (dereferenced instances) for the GC?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, profiling

I am using a bunch of `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`s in my application and the GC overhead is huge. How do I check if the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is the culprit? Is there a standard way in Java to profile these data structures for memory allocation/deallocation?

Comment: Read the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349062/how-to-profile-jvm-memory-in-the-code

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to write a simple test program and run it with the `-verbose:gc` JVM option. For example, the code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class TestGC {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();

        String[] strings = new String[1024];

        for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            strings[i] = "string" + i;
        }

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        System.out.println("Starting...");

        while(true) {
            for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) queue.offer(strings[i]);
            for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) queue.poll();
        }
    }
}
```

Produces the output:

```
$ java -verbose:gc TestGC
[GC 1352K->560K(62976K), 0.0015210 secs]
[Full GC 560K->440K(62976K), 0.0118410 secs]
Starting...
[GC 17336K->536K(62976K), 0.0005950 secs]
[GC 17432K->536K(62976K), 0.0006130 secs]
[GC 17432K->504K(62976K), 0.0005830 secs]
[GC 17400K->504K(62976K), 0.0010940 secs]
[GC 17400K->536K(77824K), 0.0006540 secs]
[GC 34328K->504K(79360K), 0.0008970 secs]
[GC 35320K->520K(111616K), 0.0008920 secs]
[GC 68104K->520K(111616K), 0.0009930 secs]
[GC 68104K->520K(152576K), 0.0006350 secs]
[GC 109064K->520K(147968K), 0.0007740 secs]
(keeps going forever)
```

Now if you want to know exactly who is the culprit you can use a profiling tool. I wrote [this memory sampler](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/2014/05/java-development-without-gc/) that you can plug in your code to quickly find out in what source code line the instances are being created. So you do:

```
MemorySampler.start();
for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) queue.offer(strings[i]);
for(int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) queue.poll();
MemorySampler.end();
if (MemorySampler.wasMemoryAllocated()) MemorySampler.printSituation();
```

And when you run you get:

```
Starting...
Memory allocated on last pass: 24576
Memory allocated total: 24576

Stack Trace:
    java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.offer(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:327)
    TestGC.main(TestGC2.java:25)
```

From where you can see that line 327 of `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is leaking instances for the GC, in other words, it is not pooling them:

```
public boolean offer(E e) {
    checkNotNull(e);
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e);

    for (Node<E> t = tail, p = t;;) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Is it possible to fix this "problem" with ConcurrentLinkedQueue?

Comment: You can try to _fix_ the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` code by pooling the `Node` instance... not trivial as this data-structure is heavily concurrent and you will have to synchronize around your object pool, adding lock contention.

Comment: Wish I could `Favorite` an answer - awesome tool!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), the official(?) java profiler. Play around with that for a little bit. You can analyze the processes AND the memory of any Java program you're running.